# How can I populate a dictionary with an enumerated list?

Tags: python, dictionary, enumerate

I have the following dictionary, where keys are integers and values are floats:

```
foo = {1:0.001,2:2.097,3:1.093,4:5.246}
```

This dictionary has keys 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Now, I remove the key '2':

```
foo = {1:0.001,3:1.093,4:5.246}
```

I only have the keys 1, 3 and 4 left. But I want these keys to be called 1, 2 and 3.

The function 'enumerate' allows me to get the list [1,2,3]:

```
some_list = []
for k,v in foo.items():
    some_list.append(k)
num_list = list(enumerate(some_list, start=1))
```

Next, I try to populate the dictionary with these new keys and the old values:

```
new_foo = {}
for i in num_list:
    for value in foo.itervalues():
        new_foo[i[0]] = value
```

However, new_foo now contains the following values:

```
{1: 5.246, 2: 5.246, 3: 5.246}
```

So every value was replaced by the last value of 'foo'. I think the problem comes from the design of my for loop, but I don't know how to solve this. Any tips?

Comment: Just use a list instead

Comment: So is order important? Presumably you want 3 to be moved to 2, 4 to move to 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreeing with the other responses that a list implements the behavior you describe, and so it probably more appropriate, but I will suggest an answer anyway.

The problem with your code is the way you are using the data structures.  Simply enumerate the items left in the dictionary:

```
new_foo = {}
for key, (old_key, value) in enumerate( sorted( foo.items() ) ):
    key = key+1  # adjust for 1-based
    new_foo[key] = value
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the list-comprehension-like style:

```
bar = dict( (k,v) for k,v in enumerate(foo.values(), start=1) )
```

But, as mentioned in the comments the ordering is going to be arbitrary, since the `dict` structure in python is unordered. To preserve the original order the following can be used:

```
bar = dict( ( i,foo[k] ) for i, k in enumerate(sorted(foo), start=1) )
```

here `sorted(foo)` returns the list of sorted keys of `foo`. `i` is the new enumeration of the sorted keys as well as the new enumeration for the new `dict`.

Comment: But this'll not retain the old mapping 'order'; the order is going to be arbitrary; Python dictionaries are not ordered!

Comment: Right. Actually the OP hasn't defined the re-mapping order properly.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to just reorder the values. You may as well use a set then.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have updated the answer to address this issue

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, it would be best to use a list instead of dict. However, in case you prefer to stick with a dict, you can do

```
foo = {j+1:foo[k] for j,k in enumerate(sorted(foo))}
```

Comment: careful: since dicts are orderless, this won't always give the right result! Also, there's a `start=` kwarg on `enumerate` that will keep you from having to do `j+1`

Comment: you're right. Also, I did not know about the start keyword => thanks (j+1 is shorter though :-)

Comment: Don't use `.keys()`; iteration over a dictionary directly gives you the keys too and saves Python having to look up the method and call it.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is the wrong structure here. Use a list; lists map contiguous integers to values, after all.

Either adjust your code to start at 0 rather than 1, or include a padding value at index 0:

```
foo = [None, 0.001, 2.097, 1.093, 5.246]
```

Deleting the `2` 'key' is then as simple as:

```
del foo[2]
```

giving you automatic renumbering of the rest of your 'keys'.

Comment: I think the question was more about how to do it with dicts rather than how to do it with lists.

Comment: @ArekBulski: without proper motivation as to why they are doing it I don't buy that argument. Unless you are creating a sparse array, there is no advantage in using a dictionary here, not when you need to re-number each and every time.

Comment: The requirement to use dict may have come from outside, and is not due to efficiency. You really do not see that?

Comment: @ArekBulski: then the OP should state so. That'd be a ridiculous requirement though.

Comment: I disagree with both statements.

Comment: @ArekBulski: then my answer failed to convey why that is. You use a dictionary to map keys to values efficiently. But if those keys are sequential and you need to re-map almost everything each time you delete something, then a list is the better choice because it offers the higher mapping efficiency at the cost of limiting the keys to sequential keys. And they *automatically are kept in order*, without having to remap.

Comment: I think you completely fail to understand that *not everything* is centered around efficiency. Sometimes a homework is given where you are supposed to do something one way or another, regardless of efficiency.

Comment: @ArekBulski: again, then it should be stated as such. There is no such statement here. In the absence of such a statement, I try to teach the right datastructures. This isn't even about performance here; it is hugely tedious to have to remap each time you delete here, not to mention confusing to future maintainers of the code.

Answer (score 0):

This looks suspiciously like Something You Should Not Do, but I'll assume for a moment that you're simplifying the process for an MCVE rather than actually trying to name your dict keys `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...`.

```
d = {1:0.001, 2:2.097, 3:1.093, 4:5.246}
del d[2]
# d == {1:0.001, 3:1.093, 4:5.246}

new_d = {idx:val for idx,val in zip(range(1,len(d)+1),
                                    (v for _,v in sorted(d.items())))}
# new_d == {1: 0.001, 2: 1.093, 3: 5.246}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foo = {1:0.001,2:2.097,3:1.093,4:5.246}
foo.pop(2)

new_foo = {i: value for i, (_, value) in enumerate(sorted(foo.items()), start=1)}

print new_foo
```

However, I'd advise you to use a normal list instead, which is designed exactly for fast lookup of gapless, numeric keys:

```
foo = [0.001, 2.097, 1.093, 5.245]
foo.pop(1) # list indices start at 0
print foo
```

Comment: careful: `foo.itervalues()` won't always give the right result since dictionaries are orderless.

Comment: @AdamSmith Right. Fixed.

Comment: You are sorting values but that is not asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert dict to list, remove specific element, then convert list to dict. Sorry, it is not a one liner.

```
In [1]: foo = {1:0.001,2:2.097,3:1.093,4:5.246}
In [2]: l=foo.values()  #[0.001, 2.097, 1.093, 5.246]
In [3]: l.pop(1) #returns 2.097, not the list
In [4]: dict(enumerate(l,1))
Out[4]: {1: 0.001, 2: 1.093, 3: 5.246}
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner that filters a sequence, then re-enumerates and constructs a dict.

```
In [1]: foo = {1:0.001, 2:2.097, 3:1.093, 4:5.246}
In [2]: selected=1

In [3]: { k:v for k,v in enumerate((foo[i] for i in foo if i<>selected), 1) }
Out[3]: {1: 2.097, 2: 1.093, 3: 5.246}
```

Comment: There is no `<>` in python...also, you forgot to do `selected=2`.

Comment: You mean Python 3.x has no `<>`. It was interchangeable with `!=` in Python 2.x. Thank you for pointing out missing selection.

Answer (score 0):

I have a more compact method.

I think it's more readable and easy to understand. You can refer as below:

```
foo = {1:0.001,2:2.097,3:1.093,4:5.246}
del foo[2]
foo.update({k:foo[4] for k in foo.iterkeys()})
print foo
```

So you can get answer you want.

```
{1: 5.246, 3: 5.246, 4: 5.246}
```